# Windows applications open automatically when TestComplete is executing scripts

Tags: uwp, testcomplete

A few Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications (Edge, Microsoft Store, Mail) open when I start running my WPF TestComplete script on a Windows 10 machine. It is not affecting the script running but in the initial test run it opens the applications and this is annoying. Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at what your test complete script does.

Comment: The question is valid, please re-open.
The issue is caused by the fact that TestComplete collects information about all processes running in the system, and if there is a "background" process, it can be restored. This affects earlier versions of Windows 10. To avoid this behavior, follow the tips in this article:
https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/general-info/configuring/windows-specifics.html#Win10